# 2 versions of jQuery -> 2 documents. why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a small page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="temp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>foo</p>
<p>bar</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and I'm trying to load two different versions of jQuery:

```
// temp.js
jQueryScriptOutputted = false;
initJQuery = function() {

  //if the jQuery object isn't available
  if (typeof(myjQuery) == 'undefined') {

    if (!jQueryScriptOutputted) {
      //only output the script once..
      jQueryScriptOutputted = true;

      //output the script (load it from google api)
      document.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"jquery-1.6.4.js\"></script>");
      document.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">var myjQuery = $.noConflict(true);</script>");
    }
    setTimeout("initJQuery()", 50);
  } else {
    myjQuery(function() {
      // Check jQuery versions
      console.log('myjQuery version = ' + myjQuery().jquery);
      console.log('$ version = ' + $().jquery);
      console.log('jQuery version = ' + jQuery().jquery);

      // Get the data of the actual poll
      document.write("Where is foo and bar?!?");
    });
  }

}
initJQuery();
```

but it seems that this loads two different documents. I mean, when you open the page, the paragraphs get lost. How come?!?

Comment: First question: Why are you trying to do this in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `document.write` after the page has loaded will overwrite the entire page with the `document.write` parameter. Consider using something else like `$().append` or `$().html` to change the markup.

i.e.

```
myjQuery(function() {
      $('body').append("<p>Where is foo and bar?!?</p>");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You must only load one version or the other.
In other words, only have one jquery library installed to the page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are writing the `<script>` tags to the document and not the `<head>`

Please see these [instructions for full information on how to dynamically load jQuery.](http://www.squidoo.com/load-jQuery-dynamically)

The tutorial explains how to do it really well.

Hope this helps.